# Possible to read RecordCount for last exececution of a querydef?

Tags: ms-access

I have a saved querydef that I am exporting, with a filter, like so:

```
DoCmd.OutputTo acOutputQuery, tmpQueryName, acSpreadsheetTypeExcel9, appDirectory & "\" & tmpQueryName & ".xls", True
```

I'd like to be able to store in an execution history table the queryname, timestamp, filter, and **recordcount** of the executed querydef.  It would be easy to re-execute in code, but it can be a very long running query, so I don't want to re-execute it.  Is there any way of reading the recordcount of the DoCmd.OutputTo, or else reading the LastExecRecordCount from the querydef itself, or some other way I could accomplish this?

Comment: First off, I don't understand why you're not using DoCmd.TransferSpreadsheet, which seems to me to be easier to use. But DoCmd actions don't have any properties accessible after the line has executed. So, the answer is that you have to use a different method of outputting the data, one which allows you to retrieve the recordcount, or you do what @tbone has suggested, check the result in the spreadsheet. I don't know, however, if that can be relied upon should the operation not complete (I don't even know if that's possible).

Comment: No particular reason....are there any advantages to TransferSpreadsheet?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In this example, since the full path to the exported excel file is known, one can do:

```
Dim xl As Excel.Workbook
    Set xl = GetObject(appDirectory & "\" & tmpQueryName & ".xls")
    Dim lastRow As Integer
    lastRow = xl.ActiveSheet.Cells(xl.ActiveSheet.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row ' the spreadsheet row number of the last row that contains data
    rowcount = lastRow - 1  'account for header row
```

Comment: @tbone: good example of rethinking the question. But I wonder -- are there any circumstances where the spreadsheet could get created, but it would not have the full results that were retrieved by the source query?

Comment: Only if you exceed the excel rowcount limit I think.  In my case I'm not too worried about being rock solid, but it may be a consideration for others.